# Can Objects in Objects be persistent? (vb .net)

Tags: vb.net, object, collections

Dim BigCollection As New Collection
    Dim SmallCollection As New Collection
    SmallCollection.Add("Hello World")
    BigCollection.Add(SmallCollection)

```
MsgBox(BigCollection(1)(1)) 'shows "Hello World
SmallCollection.Clear()
MsgBox(BigCollection(1)(1)) 'ERROR (Collection is empty)
```

I want that once I put something in the BigCollection it stays there, I dont want it to be changeable from outside. I want to be able to clear the SmallCollection but it should not be cleared in the BigCollection. Any Ideas?
Maybe it is bad approach, I am not the .net guru here yet ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a collection that shouldn't ever change, then you should expose it via a `ReadOnlyCollection(Of T)`.  Creating one from a standard `Collection` type has fairly awkward syntax though.

```
Dim completeSmall As New ReadOnlyCollection(Of Object)(SmallCollection.Cast(Of Object))
```

It would be easier if you started out with `List(Of Object)` instead of `Collection`.  The final syntax is a bit easier to read

```
Dim SmallCollection As New List(Of Object)()
...
Dim completeSmall As New ReadOnlyCollection(Of Object)(SmallCollection)
```